# Active Directory Script: DSMOVE failed

Tags: windows, active-directory, scripting

```
DSQUERY user -inactive 4 | DSMOVE -newparent <distinguished name of target OU>
```

Running this script and getting "dsmove failed (user) is an unknown parameter".

If I run the dsquery w/o the dsmove, it cleanly pulls a list for me. If I run with just one account, it works as well.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this working, here's what I did:

batch file that reads the below with a correlating windows sch task that runs the bat. Works like a champ.

Remember in 2008 to check the "run with highest privileges" and to change the run to "run whether user is logged on or not".

```
for /f "Tokens=*" %%s in ('dsquery computer -inactive 5 -limit 0') do ( 
DSMOVE %%s -newparent "OU=Computers,OU=Quarantine,OU=MyOu,DC=MyDomain,DC=local" 
)
```

Comment: Would be nice if Microsoft fixed this.

Comment: thanks that solved this problem for me however it only worked when I did it without the brackets around the DO action. for /f "Tokens=*" %%s in ('dsquery computer -inactive 8 -limit 1000') do DSMOVE %%s -newparent "OU=DisabledComputers,DC=DomainName,DC=local"